# Python extract PDF data conditionally

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have few chapters in pdf file showed in the image below. I want to extract the data (red line) after the bold sentences 
 My current code able to loop through all the pages and extract all text. But how to extract those after bold sentences? 
[image]
[image] 
Sample code:

```
import PyPDF2

filename = "test.pdf"
pdfFileObj = open(filename, 'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
num_pages = pdfReader.numPages
count = 0
text = ""

while count < num_pages:
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)
    count += 1
    text += pageObj.extractText()

print(text)
```

Comment: Are you willing to do something that detects bold text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`pdfplumber`**](https://pypi.org/project/pdfplumber/) with [**`char`**](https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber#char-properties) properties.

```
import pdfplumber

with pdfplumber.open("test.pdf") as pdf: 

    for text in pdf.pages:
        normal_text = text.filter(lambda obj: obj["object_type"] == "char" and not "Bold" in obj["fontname"])

        print(normal_text.extract_text())
```

**Note** : `fontname` is the name of the character's font face (e.g, Bold).